# Remove leading zeros in array

Tags: javascript

Example arrays:

```
[0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 63, 0]
[243, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0]
[0]
```

Wanted arrays:

```
[14, 0, 63, 0]
[243, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0]
[]
[]
```

I tried using `filter` method `.filter(val => val)` but it remove all zeros from array.

Comment: Try to share your code to us could see what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a closure over `last` which is `false` for the first falsy values.

```js
const
    filter = array => array.filter((last => v => last = last || v)(false));

console.log(filter([0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 63, 0]));
console.log(filter([243, 0, 0, 0, 1]));
console.log(filter([0, 0, 1, 0]));
console.log(filter([0, 0]));
console.log(filter([0]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Could you explain this part `(last => v => last = last || v)(false)`, what is `last` and `v`. Couldn't found any information in mdn docs

Comment: last is a variable with start value `false` and `v` is an item of the array. basically it is a nested function which is first called with `false` and the second function is the callback for filtering.

Answer (score 3):

This is all you need.

```js
const arr = [0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 63, 0];

while (arr.indexOf(0) === 0) {
  arr.shift()
}

console.log(arr)
```

Extract to a function

```js
function leftTrim(array, trimBy = 0) {
  // prevents mutation of original array
  const _array = [...array];

  while (_array.indexOf(trimBy) === 0) {
    _array.shift()
  }

  return _array;
}

// trim left by 0 (default)
console.log(leftTrim([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]));
// trim left by 1
console.log(leftTrim([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], 1));
```

Comment: Great answer, I wish I could selected multiple answers as correct one, but Nina Scholz was first and I prefer methods over loops

Comment: Actually this answer is inefficient. You don't need to search for the index of the first element that is 0. All you need to do is check the first element of the array against 0!

Answer (score 2):

And here as a public service the internals of the accepted answer: 
Two words: Closure-functions !

Normally, we know the filter-function as such

```
/**
* Returns the elements of an array that meet the condition specified in a callback function.
* @param callbackfn A function that accepts up to three arguments. The filter method calls the callbackfn function one time for each element in the array.
* @param thisArg An object to which the this keyword can refer in the callbackfn function. If thisArg is omitted, undefined is used as the this value.
*/
filter(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): T[];
```

So now we have this statement:

```
filter = array => array.filter((last => v => last = last || v)(false));
```

Which expands to:

```
filter = array => array.filter(
    function(last)
    {
        return function(v)
        {
             return last = last || v;
        };
    }(false)
);
```

Which expands further to:

```
filter = function(array)
{
       return array.filter(
             function(last)
             {
                    return function(v)
                    {
                           return last = last || v;
                    }
             }
             (false)
       );
};
```

And now we see the trick:
Instead of a global-variable, we declare a variable in a closure-function. 
Because we declare the variable as an argument to the closure function, which we initialize with false, we can save us the var/let/const-statement.

Hooray to arrow-functions ! 
With their help, it's much more evident what happens ...
(okay, granted, maybe i should use them more ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using while. Easy to understand in single loop.
You need to loop till you get first non zero element. Once you get that just start pushing the rest of elements in result array and return it.

```js
function removeLeadingZeros(arr){
    let i=0;
    let result =[];
    while(arr[i]===0){
        i++;        
    }
     while(i<arr.length){
      result.push(arr[i]);
      i++;
   }
    console.log(result);
}

removeLeadingZeros([0,0,0,14,0,6,0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

as a  function

```
function removeLeading = function(char, arr) {
    let finish = false;
    return arr.filter(i => {
        if (finish) return true;
        
        if (i != char) finish=  true;
        return i != char;
    })
} 
removeLeading(0, [0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 63, 0])
```

or as prototype function

```
Array.prototype.removeLeading = function(char) {
    let finish = false;
    return this.filter(i => {
        if (finish) return true;
        
        if (i != char) finish=  true;
        return i != char;
    })
} 
[0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 63, 0].removeLeading(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the first index having a non zero value using [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and then use [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the rest of the elements

```js
const removeLeadingZeroes = (arr) => {
    const index = arr.findIndex(Boolean);
    return index !== -1 ? arr.slice(index) : [];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for array: [false, 0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0] or ["", 0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0], but otherwise fine

Comment: Yes, you are right. It will just find the index of first truthy value and use that index to slice. If the array contains elements which are not numbers, we have to write a more appropriate logic inside findIndex. I kept the logic simple as in the question example arrays were all having numbers only